# Google Maps v3 for GWT: How to use map.setControls(JsArray<MVCArray<Node>> controls)?

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, jsni

As you know the official Google Maps API v3 for GWT is announced here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwt-google-apis/6SO5kCDqb-k

I need to use the following method of GoogleMap class:

```
map.setControls(JsArray<MVCArray<Node>> controls)
```

How do I construct the argument?

```
JsArray<MVCArray<Node>> controls
```

For example, How to put a GWT Label on TOP_LEFT of the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
textbox.setText("textbox123");
MVCArray<Node> array = MVCArray.create();
array.push(textbox.getElement());
map.getControls().set((int)ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP.getValue(), array);
```